# Why is style.css not loading through the functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

```
<?php

/*
# =======================================
# functions.php
#
# The theme's Function
# =======================================

*/

/*---------------------------------------*/
/* 1. CONSTANTS */
/*---------------------------------------*/

define('THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
define('IMAGES', THEMEROOT.'/img');
define('JS', THEMEROOT.'/js');


/*---------------------------------------*/
/* 2. SCRIPTS */
/*---------------------------------------*/
if(!function_exists('hydrogen_scripts')) {
    function hydrogen_scripts () {

        /* Load the stylesheets. */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', THEMEROOT . 'style.css' );
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hydrogen_scripts');

}
```

What mistake am I doing that this is not able to load the style.css? Any idea? Looks like some subtle mistake that is not visible.

Comment: Glad to hear, thanks! Not sure about the downvote. Remembering what functions do/don't return a trailing slash can be tricky. There is a function called [`trailingslashit( $string )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit) which will add a trailing slash if `$string` does not already have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL returned by `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` does not have a slash, so you need to add one .E.g.:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', THEMEROOT . '/style.css' );
```